# CosmosDB - ARRAY_CONTAINS in ObjectArray check for two properties

Tags: arrays, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a table in Cosmos with the following structure:

```
{
    "id": "123",
    "name": "test",
    "lastname": "test",
    "email": "test.test@test.com",
    "dni": "12345678",
    "username": "test",
    "role": "Admin",
    "costCenter": null,
    "password": "064d141b329ddabb0b0c8488b959b5b725c9e7b94b7f7a48a54076068bf88106",
    "Permissions": {},
    "AlertsConfiguration": [
        {
            "Code": "1",
            "isEnabled": true,
            "Details": "test"
        },
        {
            "Code": "2",
            "isEnabled": false,
            "Details": "test"
        },
        {
            "Code": "3",
            "isEnabled": false,
            "Details": "test"
        },
        {
            "Code": "4",
            "isEnabled": false,
            "Details": "test"
        },
        {
            "Code": "5",
            "isEnabled": false,
            "Details": "test"
        }
    ],
}
```

and I'm trying to get all the records of the table that matches in the `AlertsConfiguration` array with the condition of `Code` 2 and `isEnabled` true

I've tried the following approach:

```
SELECT c.id FROM c WHERE 
    (ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.AlertsConfiguration,{"Code": "2"},true) and
     ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.AlertsConfiguration,{"isEnabled":true},true))
```

But this returns all the records no matter if `isEnabled` is true or false

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that each of your `ARRAY_CONTAINS()` clauses is applied to the entire `AlertsConfiguration` array. So, as long as a document has one array element with `Code` = `"2"` and one array element with `isEnabled` = `true` you'll get that document.

For both criteria to be applied to the same document element, change your `ARRAY_CONTAINS()` a bit:

```sql
SELECT c.id
FROM c
where array_contains(c.AlertsConfiguration, {"Code":"2", "isEnabled":true}, true)
```

This query will now only select documents where an array element has both `Code` = `"2"` and `isEnabled` = `true`.